# Should a java package have only one public class?

Tags: java, package

I tired creating a package with one public class and one with multiple public classes and then import them through another package and both times the program worked. I understand the difference, in the first i can only use the methods of the one public class, but that class can use other classes in its package, and when more classes are public i can directly access all those classes through the alien package.

Now when we import java.util.Scanner, and we import java.util.ArrayList isn't this the same package? When we import our package with one public class it only shows the one public. That means that java.util has multiple public classes, or?

Also what does that java. mean, does it make the difference between my package and java library packages?

Comment: When you create a source-code file for Java, it’s commonly called a compilation unit (sometimes a translation unit). Each compilation unit must have a name ending in .java, and inside the compilation unit there can be a public class that must have the same name as the file (including capitalization, but excluding the .java file name extension). There can be only one public class in each compilation unit; otherwise, the compiler will complain.

Comment: If there are additional classes in that compilation unit, they are hidden from the world outside that package because they’re not public, and they comprise “support” classes for the main public class.

That's form Bruce Eckel. Does this only mean that every public class will get its own file but a non public wont?

Comment: @StefS: it's too early for you to mess with nested classes (i.e. classes defined inside other classes). Start by learning the basic stuff and, for now, consider that each class must be defined in its own file. Only when you're comfortable with these basics, then read the Java tutorial about nested classes.

Comment: @JBNizet: ah, ofcourse. I don't know what I was thinking. I'll remove it since it's wrong in its entirety, I had `private` classes in mind.

Comment: @JBNizet: Right, well it's cause in order to explain about why use packages and why we use import, the book i read gives this kind of introduction...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a package can have multiple `public` classes.

Creating a new package for every `public` class would be extremely cumbersome and provide no overview at all.

`java.` are just the standard libraries that come with the JDK/JRE.

Packages are really just like folders on your system. You can have multiple files in a folder without a problem.

Typically packages are structured in a way that they combine related classes to make it easier for the developer. If you want to have no packages at all, or you want a new package for every class: it doesn't matter. You'll be your own worst enemy, but it is surely possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

means: let me use the class `ArrayList`, which is in the package `java.util`, by only typing `ArrayList` and not `java.util.ArrayList`.

`java.util` is the name of the package, nothing else. It's where the Java developers chose to store the `ArrayList` class. It's not different from any other package name, except you're not allowed to use the `java` package for your own classes, because it's reserved for standard Java classes.

```
import java.util.*;
```

means: let me use all the classes of the package `java.util` (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Collection`, etc.) by typing their simple name (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList`, `Collection`, etc.) instead of their fully qualified name (`java.util.ArrayList`, `java.util.LinkedList`, `java.util.Collection`, etc.)

All these classes are public (as documented in their javadoc). If they weren't public, you wouldn't be able to use them in your own classes.